# C- Find the current line of my opened text file

Tags: c, file, data-manipulation

I need a solution to find the current used line in text file.
I opened it with:

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(“data.txt”, “ r+“);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "current used line"?

Comment: If you need specifications I’ll send the complete piece of code.

Comment: Yes, you need to add more details. Please read [ask].

Comment: My file cursor is at line two(for example) and I want to get that number for later use.

Comment: @IsaacChabot you have to keep this number  yourself. Just increment it with every line you read from the file.

Comment: Ok ,but my file in question  doesn’t have a permanent line number so yeahh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep track of which line in a file containing lines of text that you're currently processing, you could use a count variable.  Here's a simple example

```
while (fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, fp) != NULL)
{
    printf("Line %d: %s", line, buffer);
    if (buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] != '\n') 
    // fgets didnt read an entire line, so increment the file pointer to
    // the start of the next line. also, output the newline since it wasn't
    // part of buffer above
    {
        int ch;
        do
        {
            ch = fgetc(fp);
        }
        while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    line++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable of type unsigned int for example and initialize it with the value of zero.

Then every time you read in a new line, increment this variable by 1:

```
unsigned int currentLine = 0;
... 
// read line
currentLine++;
```

Comment: Thank you either. I will need it also.